# gpg-agent running but command line tools missing

Tags: terminal, command-line, gpg

When I was trying to configure my gpg-agent, there were was no command line tool i.e. `/usr/local/bin/gpg-agent` doesn't exist (nor does it exist in the other dirs in my `PATH` variable: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/universal-darwin`

I'm running an M1 MacBook Pro, Monterey 12.3.1; I don't know what version of `gpg-agent` is running because I can't find it; also running `gpg 2.3.4`.

This is a brand new machine and MacOS is very unfamiliar to me: I normally run Arch Linux but this is a work machine.

This is confusing to me because I found a `gpg-agent` process running using `top` and similar programs. I don't know how Apple structures it's file system so I don't know were else I should look. Can someone help me understand how `gpg-agent` could be running even though it doesn't seem to be installed in any of the usual places?

(Not sure if this is the right place this kind of question. I'm new here please be nice)

Comment: gpg-agent isn't part of a default installation, do you have any idea which 3rd party application might include it? What is the output of `ps -e | grep gpg`? Is there a `/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin` on your system?

Comment: thanks for your comment, i helped me find it

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was installed in `/usr/local/gnupg-2.3/bin` there's a symlink for the `gpg` in there to `/usr/local/bin` but not one for `gpg-agent`. Not sure how it's still running or what program is starting it but that's a different question and something I'll have to figure out myself.